# Facing problem while running Electron+React Application

Tags: reactjs, electron

I have created **Electron+ React Desktop Application.** I am facing issues when I try to load with **"index.html"** because it is loading **only** simple **js** and not jsx(react code).Please guide me through this.

This is in Main.js

mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${path.join(__dirname,'../build/index.html')}`);

This is my index.html loading index.js which has react code

require("../src/index.html")

Thanks

Comment: please provide some code that shows what you are trying to do

Comment: This is very unclear. What issues are you facing what code did you write?

Answer (score 0):

try using `url.format` instead. [Here is the link to the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_format_urlobject).

Something like this.

```
    mainWindow.loadURL(isDev
    ? url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
      }),
    : url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, '../build/index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
      })
    );
```

Comment: There is no problem with path but our index.js that is included in index.html is not loading react code but js only, any idea how to solve this